# Roll back Google App after update

Tags: updates, uninstallation

Is there an easy way to roll back the Google App to a previous version?  It really looks awful with the new colors and font.  Is a factory reset the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the system settings (steps may be a little different depending on your device):

1. Menu button.
2. Manage apps.
3. Google App.
4. Uninstall updates.

Also go to the Google App in the Google Play Store to uncheck the "Auto-update" option for the app.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Ah :) There was the missing link. "in the Google Play Store" refers to the app, not the website, right? ;)

Comment: Nobody here realizes that you can't uninstall updates for the effing Google App.

Comment: @amt528 - On my Galaxy S3 the option exists to uninstall updates for the Google App. Since you did not [originally] specify your device, I can only suggest what would be an typical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a factory reset.

Here what you can do :

1. Open System Settings and uninstall the Google App you want to downgrade
2. Search the applications version you want to use on [ApkMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/), download it and install it.

---

For Google Application that can not be uninstall in system settings **(you will need a root access)** :

1. Download [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=fr)
2. Open Titanium, backup and uninstall the Google App you want to downgrade
3. Search the applications version you want to use on [ApkMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/), download it and install it.

---

Do not forget to disable auto-update in Google Play Store :

**Google Play Store** > **Settings** > **Automatics updates** > **Do not automatically update applications**.

Comment: When done, wait ~24h – and you'll have that update back. Google apps usually update themselves automatically (not all of them, though – but e.g. Playstore and GServices do).

Comment: OP mentioned "the new colors and font" so I don't think he is talking about GServices. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Agreed it's not the GServices. Confusing is that "Google app" could mean any app made by Google – and that there's one of them in fact just named "Google" (the search app) as well. For the most of them it's true you can keep them from auto-updating – but others (like GServices and GPlay) do not even appear in "my apps". Though I have to admit I didn't try TiBu on those :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Pixel XL, 128gig, black, on Verizon.

1. Dragged down top menu
2. Clicked on Gear
3. Clicked on Apps
4. Scroll to and select Google App
5. Clicked Tripple Dot in upper right corner
6. Selected only option Uninstall Updates

Working better, but not perfect.

Comment: Worked, but it also reset the home screen to factory default, meaning all icons are deleted and have to be manually restored from the apps screen, which is at least annoying, and possibly scary if people think all their apps have been deleted and they don't know how to find them.